# Tailwind Button ignoring background colour

Tags: button, tailwind-css

I have a laravel component for a submit button in Tailwind.

The button code is:

```
<div class="{{ $position }} mt-4">
<button type="submit"
    class="inline-flex items-center h-10 px-5 text-indigo-100 bg-indigo-600 rounded-lg focus:shadow-outline hover:bg-indigo-800"  style="{{ addShadow() }}"
    @if (!empty($onClick))
      onclick="{{ $onClick }}"
     @endif
     >
    @fas('{{ $icon }}')
    <span class="ml-2">{{ $label }}</span>
</button>
```

The things like position, icon, label, onclick are passed in OK.

My problem is that unless the mouse is over the button it deos not really appear as can be seen from the image attach. The first shows as the page opens and the second is as the mouse is over.

I simply cannot get this to work!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I normally actually upload and test in an online area, but with the new Laravel Vite changes are not made. If this is done in localhost and then uploaded the app.css etc it works.